# Do all static members defined in an interface have to be defined with default implementation?

Tags: c#, interface, static-methods

I have recently been fooling around with static members in an interface. Particularly with static methods. I have noticed that whenever I define a static method in an interface I am obligated to define it with default implementation. Or else compile time error [CS0501](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0501) will occur. What I am wondering is, is it obligatory that all static members, defined in an interface be defined with default implementation? Or does this only apply to static methods defined in an interface?

```
public interface IFoo
{
    public static void MethodFoo()
    {
       //implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: With preview compiler I believe you can make the method `abstract`. Or perhaps that's a generally available thing

Comment: @gunr2171 "No" that static members (besides static methods which are) are not obligated to be defined with defualt implemenation when defined in an interface?

Comment: What were you hoping to accomplish that the compiler won't let you?

Comment: If you don't provide an implementation for a static method, where do you expect the implementation to be provided? Providing the implementation in a class that implements the interface defeats the purpose of making the member static.

Comment: @gunr217 very true. However, I am asking if any other member, defined as static (besides a static method) in an interface, must be defined with default implementation. Or does that only apply to static methods?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Just wanted to clarify the concept of static members defined in interface.  What's your opinion on static members defined in an interface. Do all static members defined in an interface have to be explicitly defined with defualt implementation. Or does that only apply to static methods?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish. There's a [good documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) outlining exactly what member types are allowed in an interface, including those new with c# 8. You can certainly try it out yourself to see if they are allowed or not. Why are you even applying static to members in an interface in the first place?

Comment: @gunr2171 I am testing what kind of members must be defined with defualt implemenation when defined in an interface (besides private members). I have actually read that documentation. As to why I ask about static members, is because when I  define a static method, it obligatory to explicitly define it with default implementation. I have tested this on other static members (besides a static method) and it seems like only static methods have to explicitly be defined with defualt implementation. Not sure if I was entirely correct though?

Comment: When you make a static method on an interface, you're not giving it a _default_ implementation, you're giving it _the_ implementation. _Default_ implementation is only for non-static things. You can't inherit static members, so there's no way to override its behavior. This goes with anything static.

Comment: @gunr2171 In that case, static members are defined with "implementation" since they cannot be overriden. While non-static members, including member defined with the private accessibilty level are defined with "defualt implementaion"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes static members must me implemented on the interface, but that's not really a "default implementation". Static members are members of the *interface*, not the *implementing class*. So you can not "defer" the implementation to an implementing type. Having a static member on an interface does not mean that "implementers must have this static member".

This is true for all static members, not just on interfaces. Static members are not inherited and can't be overridden.

In other words, you can't do:

```
interface IFoo{
   static virtual void Bar();
}

class Fizz : IFoo:
{
   static void Bar() {
      Console.WriteLine("In Fizz");
   }
}

Class Buzz : IFoo:
{
   static void Bar() {
      Console.WriteLine("In Buzz");
   }
}
```

If you could, what would `IFoo.Bar()` mean? How would the compiler know what method to bind to?

Comment: In that case, static members are defined with "implementation". While non-static members, including members defined with the private accessibilty level are defined with "defualt implementaion"?

Comment: If a non-static member has an implementation, yes that would be a "default" implementation, meaning that implementers don't have to create their own implementation. That concept is irrelevant for statics because they aren't inherited.

Comment: So basically because the implementation of a static member cannot be overriden it is considered "implementation" instead of "default implementation"? Or is it because  the implementation of a static member cannot be inherited?

Comment: Yes, though usually the term "implementation" isn't even used in the static case. It's more common to say "a static method, no matter if it's in a class or an interface, defines its own body, since nothing else can supply it since static methods cannot be overridden". (Yet. [They are considering virtual/abstract static methods](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/static-abstracts-in-interfaces.md), which just makes my head hurt, but it's not in the language yet.)

Comment: @JoeSewell I have notice that defining a static method with an empty body is still considered as giving it implementation. But I thought code actually had to be present within the delimeters { } for the member to be considered has having implementation?

Comment: If the method's return type is `void`, then the body can be blank. The method will simply do nothing when called. A blank body is still a body.

Comment: @JoeSewell A blank body is still considered as implementation? Is that what you meant by "A blank body is still a body"?

Comment: Yes, I just prefer saying "body" with static methods because it seems more natural to me. But a static method's body (i.e. the code declared with the method) always provides its implementation, so they are synonymous here.