# Why static members in interfaces are not enforced?

Tags: c#, interface, .net-7.0

With C# 11 and .NET 7 we can define static members in interfaces, but why is it that the class which implements this interface

```
public interface IHasInstance<T>
{
    static T Instance { get; set; }
}
```

isn't enforced to have a static property name Interface such as

```
internal static MyClass Instance { get; } = new();
```

EDIT: I actually wanted to know how to enforce implementing the static member defined in the interface and I wasn't aware I have to use the `abstract` modifier to make it work that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do all static members defined in an interface have to be defined with default implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594621/do-all-static-members-defined-in-an-interface-have-to-be-defined-with-default-im)

Comment: That question predates C# 11. We now have `abstract static` interface members, which do require implementation by the class.

Comment: @madreflection There isn't `abstract static` in the OP's code though?

Comment: @GSerg: That's right, but what OP *intended* is what `abstract static` does, to require the class to implement the static member. Your duplicate is not wrong; that correctly explains why the class isn't required to implement it. I'm pointing out how to achieve what OP intended in addition to that.

Comment: That said, it's a bit harsh to close with that duplicate on such a strict interpretation of the question when the intent is clearly different. There's probably a better duplicate out there.

Comment: @GSerg @madreflection Thank you both for your comments. The other SO question did clarify some misunderstandings on my part, and also it is true that I didn't know I have to use the ```abstract``` modifier to enforce the static member on classes implementing the interface. @madreflection If you could make an answer so I can accept it, I'd be grateful. Again, thank you both for taking the time.

Comment: Providing interfaces with an implementation in the interface declaration was purely meant as a refactoring tool.  Solves the very practical problem of having interface implementations frozen in time in modules that are no longer maintainable.  The entire point was to *not* force the implementing class to provide an implementation, as interfaces normally do.  Syntax that was not well designed, leading to a feature that is not well understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `static T Instance { get; set; }` is not a part of an interface contract, it is part of (yep, it sounds strange, but) interface implementation: ability to specify static fields, methods, properties, indexers, and events was added in C# 8 with [default implementations in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods) feature:

> The syntax for an interface is extended to permit
>
> - ...
> - member declarations that declare static fields, methods, properties, indexers, and events;
> - ...

> Interfaces may not contain instance state. While static fields are now permitted, instance fields are not permitted in interfaces. Instance auto-properties are not supported in interfaces, as they would implicitly declare a hidden field.

Note that the main goal of this particular addition is:

> Static and private methods permit useful refactoring and organization of code used to implement the interface's public API.

C# 11 actually has another feature added which allows to achieve your goal - [abstract static members in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces):

```cs
public interface IHaveInstance<T>
{
    static abstract T Instance { get; set; }
}

class Bar : IHaveInstance<Bar>
{
    // now is required
    public static Bar Instance { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Another feature added with C# 11 in .NET 7 is [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math) which actually heavily utilizes abstract static members.